# can't target gravityform input or field ID in filter

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a filter/validation script that only accepts emails from a certain domain. This is working pretty good but I need to have it on a specific from input ID:

As per https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_validation/#11-email-validation-by-third-party-api#usage :

> You can also target a specific field by adding the form id and field
>   id after the hook name.
>
> `//The following declaration targets field 1 in form 6 add_filter(`
>   `'gform_field_validation_6_1', 'your_function_name', 10, 4 );`

Currently my code looks like this:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation', function ( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    if ( ! $result['is_valid'] && $field->get_input_type() === 'email' && strpos($field->get_field_input(), 'company.com') === true) {
        $result['is_valid'] = true;
        $result['message']  = '';
    } else {
        $result['is_valid'] = false;
        $result['message']  = 'E-Mail must be a company.com address';
    }

    return $result;
}, 10, 4 );
```

My form and input IDs are confirmed as 1 and 13, respectively:

[image]

When I change the code to the following, the script stops working:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_13_1', function ( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    if ( ! $result['is_valid'] && $field->get_input_type() === 'email' && strpos($field->get_field_input(), 'company.com') === true) {
        $result['is_valid'] = true;
        $result['message']  = '';
    } else {
        $result['is_valid'] = false;
        $result['message']  = 'E-Mail must be a company.com address';
    }

    return $result;
}, 10, 4 );
```

Is there another way I need to check my form ID? What is missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation `gform_field_validation_6_1` means that it targets `field 1` in `form 6`.

You form id is 1 and input field id is 13 so the filter should be `gform_field_validation_1_13`.